# Give the simplest example for Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I registered the project in Google Api Console
updated android sdk ->extra->google cloud messaging for android
imported library gcm.jar in my project
necessary classes visible. Now I want to write a simple example of using Google Cloud Messaging for Android. but all the examples are very complex and confusing. 
please tell me the simplest example for android. so that the application starts up and take notice in the form of any text. the simplest example. and if it can be an example of how to make a server kotoorye will send these messages.

Comment: there are many example out there in google ...did you tried anything? any issues in examples you tired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [repository](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/) this contains all the necessary code for creating a working client and server implementation for GCM.

To learn about GCM take a look at the [official site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Good luck!

Comment: I can not understand with an example (((what URL need to write?